# Cannot set Visibility or call Show, ShowDialog, Close, or Hide while window is closing. in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-server-2003

I am working with wpf-C#, I am facing an issue : that is - on window closing, visibility is set to hidden and e.Cancel to true. It is working as expected in Windows 7. But when I tested it with Windows Server 2003 SP2 ,.Net framework 3.5, It is not working as expected.That means, It hides from the user but when I tried to show on next time it shows the error- Cannot set Visibility or call Show, ShowDialog, Close, or Hide while window is closing. It happens only in Windows server 2003. But in Windows 7 it works fine.

The piece of code is like this:

```
private void OnClosing( object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e )
{
    try
    {
        this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        NeMIASMessageBox.ShowInformationMessageBox(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Kindly Anybody can help me as early as possible....???

Comment: Also post the code used to show the window again + indicate at what line the exception occurs,

Comment: try Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(delegate {this.ShowInTaskbar = false;},DispatcherPriority.Input); check different priorities .

Comment: It worked with   
                              typeof(Window).GetField("_isClosing", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).SetValue(this, false);
 e.Cancel = true;
                                                              this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; Can you say why?